# How to insert Image to Class Property in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want all my class objects has a unique image. This is my CardClass:

```
class CardClass {
  int deger;
  String tip;
  int id;
  String image;

  CardClass(this.deger, this.tip, this.id, this.image);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${deger}, ${tip}}';
  }
}
```

How can I define an image for all my objects? Thank you.

```
lass CardBrain {
  List<CardClass> cardbank = [
    CardClass(1, "maca", 1, "images/dice1.png")]
```

My Pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/dice1.png
```

It says:

Unable to load asset: images/dice1.png

[image]

Comment: This code doesn't attempt to open a `cardClass.image`.  Show the code that does that.  And please use text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

i did the same with having a string attribute in my Class containing the image's path.

class myClass(){String imagePath;[...]}

myClass myClassVariable = myClass(imagePath: 'Path');

i am loading the image when i need it by using Image.assets Widget.

Image.asset(
myClassVariable.imagePath,
width:50,
height:50,
),